# How to include custom block in default block?

Tags: magento-1.7, xml, layout

I have created a custom Extension.

In this Extension, I need to show some content in product description page.

How can i include that block using layout.xml.

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            .
            .
            .
            <-- My Block Load Here -->
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
            .
            .
            .
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

My Block Here:

```
<block type="xxx/yyyy" name="xxx.content" as="" template="xxx/xxx.phtml" />
```

What are the code add in my module xml file(app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/xxx.xml).

```
I no need to update anything in default phtml and layout file.
```

Please share your ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use inside your layout.xml

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="xxx/yyyy" name="xxx.content" as="" template="xxx/xxx.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

To position the block where you want, you can use `before` and `after` tags in your block as stated [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts).

Comment: I need to add my content in before add-to-cart button @mbalparda

Comment: Get the name of the block and do         <block type="xxx/yyyy" name="xxx.content" before="addto" as="" template="xxx/xxx.phtml" />

Comment: @VijayS. try adding an attribute `before="addto"` to the block tag in the example above.

Comment: @Marius I have try that above code its not working.

Comment: @Marius Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484955/magento-xml-using-before-after-to-place-blocks-hardly-ever-works?answertab=votes#tab-top  is any way to force include custom block

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR I guess there is not. If there was, I'm sure Alan Storm would have put it in the answer.

Comment: @Marius is any other way to include custome block with before and after

Comment: @Marius can we use output="toHtml" in block

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaramR. Sorry but I have no idea. The only way I know to do this is to use a different template for the product view page. Basically copy the view template in your custom module, modify the block using layout files and tell it to use your template and then modify your template and inject your block there. Not very elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Here the complete

First,check your current render is `catalog_product_view`

```
<catalog_product_view>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Then you reference  blog name is `name="product.info"`
So, put

```
<reference name="product.info">
</reference>
```

Third: put you block ,whose name should be unique.

```
<reference name="product.info">
        <block type="xxx/yyyy" name="xxx.content" as="" template="xxx/xxx.phtml" />
    </reference>
```

xxx.content is block name ,it is unique.

Then ,call this `block using  below code  in phtml of reference block`

```
$this->getChildHtml('blockname');
```

As i define block name is  xxx.content 
then `echo  $this->getChildHtml('xxx.content'); in view.phtml file` As  c`atalog/product/view.phtml is reference phtml file`

Comment: I dont want to add any code in phtml file. Please see my question

Comment: Vijay,could not clearly in understrand  "some content in product description page".Can you explain

Comment: its may be a Html design, or content